# Snakemake copy one file to multiple files

Tags: snakemake

I have several folders

```
folder_1234
folder_4321
```

I want to copy one file `myfile.sh` from one folders (already exists) to all folders and then change the number inside the file using `sed`:

```
SAMPLE=["1234","4321"]
rule all:
    input:
        expand("workdir/folder_{sample}/myfile.sh", sample=SAMPLES)
rule copy:
    input:
        copy_from="/path/to/folder_1234/myfile.sh"
    output:
        copy_to="workdir/folder_{sample}/myfile.sh"
    shell:
        """
        cp {input.copy_from} {output.copy_to}
        sed "s/folder_1234/folder_{sample}/g" folder_{sample}/myfile.sh
        """
```

This gives me an error:

```
NameError: The name 'sample' is unknown in this context. Did you mean 'wildcards.sample'?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `shell` command, wildcard syntax here would be `{wildcards.sample}` instead of `{sample}`. For documentation on wildcards usage, [see here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#wildcards).